# How do I add/remove text inputs on button click in React-native?

Tags: react-native

[This is kind of what I want to achieve in my react native app. How should I go about it?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bB0Ns.gif)

Comment: Have you tried something already ?

Comment: try something and then ask for help when you find a problem

Answer (score 0):

this is just an idea to show or hide a `TextInput` upon button press

```
return (
    <View>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this.setState({show : !this.state.show})}>
            <Text>Click Here</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        {this.state.show ? <TextInput
                                Value={this.state.value}
                                onChangeText={value => this.setState({value})}
                           />
                          : null}
    </View>
);
```

Initialize `this.state.show` as either `true` or `false` according to your requirement.

Your question could have been more clearer along with your efforts that you had tried